# Is series convergent/divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I need to find out is series convergent or not
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{5k-2}{(3{k}^{2}-2)\sqrt[3]{k+6}}
$$
How can I do that? Can you show step-by step solution?

Comment: yes it is convergent (or in that case may be divergent).. So what....?

Comment: Edited it to become more proper

Comment: just as first step, remove all those $5,2$in the numerator and $3,2,6$ in the denominator... can you see for convergence/divergence now...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms are positive, so the strategy "find an equivalent" works. We can show that $$\frac{5k-2}{(3k^2-2)\sqrt[3]{k+6}}\sim\frac{5k}{3k^2k^{1/3}}=\frac 53\frac{1}{k^{4/3}}.$$

Comment: :) that is exactly what i have said in my comment... :)

Comment: @john : This coincidence should tell you what should be the obvious way to proceed in this type of problems..

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

- $5k - 2 < 5k$ for all $k$
- $3k^2 - 2 > 2k^2$ for $k > 1$
- $\sqrt[3]{k + 6} > \sqrt[3]{k}$ for all $k$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{5k-2}{(3{k}^{2}-2)\sqrt[3]{k+6}}=\Theta\left(\frac{k}{k^2\cdot\sqrt[3]{k}}\right)=\Theta\left(\frac1{k^{4/3}}\right)\qquad \&\qquad 4/3\gt1$$
Sorry, no other step...